# Android - issue in controlling builtin app using Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I am writing an android testing application which automates testing on the device.

I am targeting facebook as my base application and writing an app using the Robotium framework in order to accomplish my requirement.

Until now i have successfully implemented a few features, but I am stuck at one point: I want to automate the "upload picture" functionality, but as soon as the upload button is clicked, the device builtin application gets activated. I could not control the default app using Robotium.

Is there any way to solve this, by writing some code using robotium or writing a layer between the OS and Robotium which can generate key stokes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.  However you might be able to make your own modified version of the built-in application and use that instead (if you can make it default and so not have to go through a selection screen), or root a phone and break its security model to use as an automated testing device.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> a layer between the OS and Robotium.

If you were ok with that, there is the black-box [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator)-Framework by google, which might be able to do that.
Additionally,

> You might want to use [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) like this:
>
> ```
> $ monkeyrunner
> >>> from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
> >>> device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
> >>> device.touch(200, 400, MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
> ```
>
> You can also do a drag, start activies etc. Have a look at the api for
>   [MonkeyDevice](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html).

(from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959385/1587329)).