# send touch events to a device via adb

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to send touch events to a device using `adb shell` command, so that I can do some basic automation for UI tests. I have followed the discussion in some previous threads regarding this.

I confirmed about getting the events and using `sendevent`, to send out 6 events for each touch ( xcoord, ycoord, `2` for press, `2` for release) and it was easy to use this information with `sendevent`, but the `getevent` command for the touchscreen device seems to generate far too many events.

Has somebody managed to send touch event from `adb` to a device? Could you please share the solution.

I am working on recording the touch events on phone. After that I wish to send the same event back to the device as part of UI testing.

Please help

Comment: Checkout http://marian.schedenig.name/2014/07/03/remote-control-your-android-phone-through-adb/

Answer (score 57):

Android comes with an `input` command-line tool that can simulate miscellaneous input events.
To simulate a `tap`, use:

```
input tap x y
```

Run the `input` command **remotely** using `adb shell`:

```
adb shell input tap x y
```

Other options are:

```
shell@m0:/ $ input
input
usage: input ...
       input text <string>
       input keyevent <key code number or name>
       input [touchscreen|touchpad|touchnavigation] tap <x> <y>
       input [touchscreen|touchpad|touchnavigation] swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)]
       input trackball press
       input trackball roll <dx> <dy>
```

Comment: I only have `text` and `keyevent`

Comment: Some android come with crippled binaries.

Answer (score 35):

To send touch event you need to do:

1. Set coordinates:

   ```
   adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 0 x
   adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 1 y
   ```
2. Send touch event (must have `0 0 0` pair):

   ```
   adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 330 1
   adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0
   ```
3. Send release finger event (must have `0 0 0` pair):

   ```
   adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 330 0
   adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0
   ```

Please note:

1. You can record events:

   ```
   adb shell getevent
   ```
2. If you use `getevent` all event values are in hex.

Comment: You mean, getevent records in hex, and sendevent only accepts decimal???

Comment: Yes, getevent prints out in hex, but works with decimal only. No errors printed, just doesn't do anything :)

Comment: What is the solution here? DO I have to convert all the hex into decimal manually?

Comment: Yes, you just have to convert it to decimal.

Answer (score 27):

I managed to record a session and replay it with only bash and adb.

This what I did, I hope it helps someone.

## Record a series of events

1. Set up the pc to record data in a file (`/tmp/android-touch-events.log`)

   ```
   $ adb shell getevent | grep --line-buffered ^/ | tee /tmp/android-touch-events.log
   ```
2. do some stuff on the phone
3. stop the adb command on the pc with `ctrl-c`

## Replay the recorded events

This command will do the hex conversion in `awk`

```
$ awk '{printf "%s %d %d %d\n", substr($1, 1, length($1) -1), strtonum("0x"$2), strtonum("0x"$3), strtonum("0x"$4)}' /tmp/android-touch-events.log | xargs -l adb shell sendevent
```

Comment: "awk: bailing out at source line 1" this error is coming. Do u have any idea ?

Comment: replay command doesn't work on OSX. xargs: illegal option -- l; awk: calling undefined function strtonum

Comment: @geeth it seems [someone has found it, too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199934/strtonum-in-os-x-not-found). Sorry by I'm on GNU/Linux.

Comment: This worked great for me, however I need to have a delay between each line.  I tried this, but it didn't work:   awk '{printf "%s %d %d %d\n", substr($1, 1, length($1) -1), strtonum("0x"$2), strtonum("0x"$3), strtonum("0x"$4);sleep 5}' android-touch-events.log | xargs -l adb shell sendevent

Comment: this answered it for me some, however, the delay seems to cause issues and the input may timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153240/how-to-sleep-for-1-second-between-each-xargs-command

Comment: @MaxChinni awesome.! but am getting  a delay between each touch which i didn't make when i recorded the input.So, how do i remove the delay and make it as it recorded? how can i repeat the task like 2-3 times ?. thank you

Comment: I still get the xargs: illegal option -- l. Which option is used in the command ?

Comment: On Mac, I fixed the xargs issue above with "-L 1".  So the whole command: gawk '{printf "%s %d %d %d\n", substr($1, 1, length($1) -1), strtonum("0x"$2), strtonum("0x"$3), strtonum("0x"$4)}' /tmp/android-touch-events.log | xargs -L 1 adb shell sendevent

Comment: I also needed to use the command "adb root" before doing this.  Otherwise, I got "sendevent: /dev/input/event5: Permission denied"

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) like this:

```
$ monkeyrunner
>>> from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
>>> device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
>>> device.touch(200, 400, MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

You can also do a drag, start activies etc.
Have a look at the api for [MonkeyDevice](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html).