# Android: Screen touch event through ADB

Tags: android, events, adb

Referencing this thread:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/8a5d8fa9229114d2/ce6e604f52b5318f?pli=1

I know following will send a touch event (5,29) on the device.

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 0 5 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 1 29 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 330 1 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 330 0 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
```

However, trying on the real device, it doesn't work. (Tried Nexus S, HTC G2 rooted)

I used

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

or

```
getevent
```

to find out which event# is the touch events and send the above code, but no luck.
(Actually I tried all event#s, but none of them work)

How do I send touch events using ADB on real devices?

For key events, I know there's:

```
input keyevent <event_code>
```

Is there such one for touch events?

I know I can record/playback touch events. However, I am asking for programmatically sending touch events.

Comment: In Froyo event sequence was changed, you can find answer here in my blog:
http://www.softteco.com/blog/android-low-level-shell-click-on-screen/

Answer (score 1):

See the (slightly adapted) answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959385/1587329:

> You might want to use [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) like this:

```
$ monkeyrunner
>>> from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
>>> device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
>>> device.touch(5, 29, MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

> You can also do a drag, start activies etc.
>   Have a look at the api for [MonkeyDevice](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)  method of View class  to send touch (down,move,up) events