# strtonum in OS X, not found

Tags: shell, awk, osx-lion

```
cmp -l "$1" "$2/$1" | awk '{printf "%08X %02X %02X\n", $1, strtonum(0$2), strtonum(0$3)}'
```

I am using command above to show the binary differences in Ubuntu, from shell script. However, this doesn't work in OS X lion, claiming that strtonum not found. Any idea how to have it in OS X or substitute it with something similar/light?

Comment: That’s a GNU extension available in gawk. You could install and use GNU awk, or maybe use [this function](http://www.uni-kassel.de/fb16/neuronale_netze/downloads/Unix_Tools/gawk-Installation/share/awk/strtonum.awk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) can be used to install the GNU version of `awk` which includes `strtonum`.  To avoid conflicts with the system `awk`, they install the GNU version as `gawk`.

For example, with the base `MacPorts` files installed:

```
sudo port install gawk
```

Comment: Even after installing gawk (`brew install gawk`), I still get `awk: calling undefined function strtonum`

Comment: @Dr.jacky try using `gawk` instead of `awk` in your script

Answer (score 0):

As it was said there is no `strtonum` on mac/BSD `awk`, but if you need to convert `hex` to `dec` there is a workaround:

```
echo 0xff | awk '{print $1+0}'
```

So just add `0` to hex value and by default `awk` converts it to decimal value.

Comment: This does not work.;  `echo 0xff | awk '{print $1+0}'` just outputs `0`.

Comment: @MarkReed it _does_ work ... for me on macOS with the native `awk`. It *doesn't work* for me on Windows in GNU Awk. So it is worse than not working.

Comment: Confirmed that it works on the `/usr/bin/awk` that ships with macOS, but not on either the GNU or AT&T (i.e. `brew install awk`) versions.

Comment: The question is about MacOS only.