# How to sleep for 1 second between each xargs command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

For example, if I execute

```
ps aux | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} echo {}
```

I want to let the shell sleep for 1 second between each `echo`.

How can I change my shell command?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I % sh -c '{ echo %; sleep 1; }'
```

Be careful with spaces and semicolons though. After every command in between brackets, semicolon is required (even after the last one).

Comment: What should I do if I need to use some $VARIABLE inside inner shell? It doesn't inherit it by default.

Comment: I think it does inherit it. On example: 'export a=abc' and then use 'echo $a %' instead of 'echo %'.

Comment: A coworker pointed out to me is that you can pipe one xargs call into another, which is handy if you have a command that's trickier to put between single quotes: `psql -c "select foo from bar" | xargs -I % sh -c '{ echo %; sleep 1; }' | xargs -L1 -I {} curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "code": "123",
  "foo": "{}"
}' "https://myapi.com/baz"`

Comment: When I try this, I'm just getting a bunch of %s printed on each line. (On Mac OS X if that helps)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `echo` by some shell script named `sleepecho` containing

```
 #!/bin/sh
 sleep 1
 echo $*
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `awk` supports it:

```
ps aux | awk '{ system("sleep 1"); print $1 }' | xargs -I {} echo {}q
```

or skip `awk` and `xargs` altogether

```
ps aux | while read -r user rest; do
    echo ${user}
    sleep 1
done
```