# Simulate Events on Android without root

Tags: android, events, root

I need to simulate touch event on android without root and on a global stage.

I think this is possible because an app called wifi keyboard does this with keyboard events.

Is there also a way to inject touch events without root? Any sample code?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use adb shell with "sendevent" :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386449/send-touch-event-from-adb-to-a-device

Comment: "I think this is possible because an app called wifi keyboard does this with keyboard events" -- it implements an `InputMethodEditor` for this purpose -- basically, a replacement soft keyboard. The user must agree to use this keyboard.

Comment: @Boldwin: That should only work from the development tools. If the OP is looking to have this work solely on-device, those techniques should not work (and if they do, it's a massive security flaw).