# How to send a touch event to iOS simulator via command line?

Tags: iphone, xcode, adb, ios-simulator, simctl

On Android we have adb commands to send touch events `adb shell input tap x y` [send touch events to a device via adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386449/send-touch-events-to-a-device-via-adb) .

How do we do the same for iOS?