# Can I close external applications with Robotium?

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I have my Android app and there are 4 buttons. Each of them calls an application like
Facebook app, Twitter app, default email app and phone call.

When I am testing these buttons with Robotium, is it possible to close the external applications from within the test script?

Comment: it is unclear what is being asked here. Are you running into an error when you're calling the app? Are you asking us to write it for you? (In which case, no, we won't).

Comment: sorry, I wrote with mistakes = (

Comment: Robotium launches other application from my android app. So I dont know which robotium commands allow to finish all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native way for robotium to be able to interact with multiple applications at once. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306529/android-issue-in-controlling-builtin-app-using-robotium). It seems like they had a similar issue.